# Sequelize condition on joined table doesn't work with limit condition

Tags: postgresql, join, subquery, sequelize.js

I have a `Supplier` model with associated `Calendar` models.

I want to fetch suppliers who either

- have a calendar which is set to available
- don't have a calendar

I can do this using the following:

```
Supplier.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Calendar,
      as: 'calendars',
      required: false,
      where: {
        start_time: { [Op.lte]: date },
        end_time: { [Op.gte]: date },
      },
    },
  ],
  where: {
    '$calendars.state$': {
      [Op.or]: [
        { [Op.in]: ['available'] },
        { [Op.eq]: null },
      ],
    },
  },
});
```

This generates the following SQL (irrelevant columns removed):

```
SELECT
  "suppliers"."uuid"
  ,"calendars"."uuid" AS "calendars.uuid"
  ,"calendars"."state" AS "calendars.state"
FROM "suppliers" AS "suppliers"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "suppliers_calendars" AS "calendars" ON
  "suppliers"."uuid" = "calendars"."supplier_id"
    AND "calendars"."start_time" <= '2019-05-27 23:00:00.000 +00:00'
    AND "calendars"."end_time" >= '2019-05-27 23:00:00.000 +00:00'
WHERE (
  ("calendars"."state" IN ('available')
    OR "calendars"."state" IS NULL
  )
)
ORDER BY "suppliers"."uuid"
;
```

Cool, as expected. Now what happens if I add a `limit`? I.e.

```
Supplier.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Calendar,
      as: 'calendars',
      required: false,
      where: {
        start_time: { [Op.lte]: date },
        end_time: { [Op.gte]: date },
      },
    },
  ],
  where: {
    '$calendars.state$': {
      [Op.or]: [
        { [Op.in]: ['available'] },
        { [Op.eq]: null },
      ],
    },
  },
  limit: 10,
});
```

This produces the following:

```
SELECT
    "suppliers".*
    ,"calendars"."uuid" AS "calendars.uuid"
    ,"calendars"."state" AS "calendars.state"
FROM (
    SELECT "suppliers"."uuid"
    FROM "suppliers" AS "suppliers"
    WHERE (
        ("calendars"."state" IN ('available')
        OR "calendars"."state" IS NULL)
    )
    ORDER BY "suppliers"."uuid"
    LIMIT 10
) AS "suppliers"
LEFT OUTER JOIN "suppliers_calendars" AS "calendars" ON
    "suppliers"."uuid" = "calendars"."supplier_id"
    AND "calendars"."start_time" <= '2019-05-27 23:00:00.000 +00:00'
    AND "calendars"."end_time" >= '2019-05-27 23:00:00.000 +00:00'
    ORDER BY "suppliers"."uuid"
```

This is a completely different query, with the main part put into a subquery and the join placed outside. But the `where` condition on the joined table is put inside the subquery, before the join has occurred, and so fails.

What is the correct approach here?

Comment: I tested a similar query of two tables associated with `hasOne()` and adding `limit` didn't restructure the query.  What kind of association joins `Supplier` and `Calendar`?

Comment: In this case it is `hasMany`. But I don't see why that should matter. Using raw SQL, this query is very simple - just need to move the WHERE condition on "calendars"."state" to the outer query, underneath the left outer join. Surely Sequelize can do this?

Comment: It should **not** matter, but it does... I tested, with MySql.  Was going to suggest you log this as a bug on github, but I see you already did.  An obvious work-around `Supplier.findAll(..).then (allResults => { let limitedResults = allResults.slice(0,10); ...`

Comment: The workaround completely bypasses the inbuilt limit function that the database provides. If that's the only solution available, then Sequelize is completely useless.

Comment: There are a few database features that Sequelize doesn't implement, or IMHO implements badly.

Comment: This particular flaw I expect will be fixed.... but not today... hence my suggestion.  If it doesn't suit you, don't use it.  Same with Sequelize - there are other choices.

Comment: For an ORM, not being able to do joins well is quite shocking.

Answer (score 1):

After about a week of hell found acceptable workaround for my case. Believe it would be helpful as found a lot of unanswered topics/issues on github.

**TL;DR; actual solution is at the end of post, just the last piece of code.**

The main idea is that Sequelize builds correct SQL query, but when having left joins we produce carthesian product, so there will be a lot of rows as query result.

Example: A and B tables. Many to many relation. If we want to get all A joined with B we will receive A * B rows, so there will be a lot of rows for each record from A with different values from B.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS a (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    title VARCHAR
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS b (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    age INTEGER
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ab (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    aid INTEGER,
    bid INTEGER
)

SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN (ab JOIN b ON b.id = ab.bid) ON a.id = ab.aid
```

In sequelize syntax:

```
class A extends Model {}
A.init({
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    title: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
});

class B extends Model {}
B.init({
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    age: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
});

A.belongsToMany(B, { foreignKey: ‘aid’, otherKey: ‘bid’, as: ‘ab’ });
B.belongsToMany(A, { foreignKey: ‘bid’, otherKey: ‘aid’, as: ‘ab’ });

A.findAll({
    distinct: true,
    include: [{ association: ‘ab’ }],
})
```

Everything works ok.

So, imagine i want to receive 10 records from A with mapped to them records from B.
When we put LIMIT 10 on this query, Sequelize build correct query but LIMIT is applied to whole query and as result we receive only 10 rows , where all of them could be for only one record from A. Example:

```
A.findAll({
    distinct: true,
    include: [{ association: ‘ab’ }],
    limit: 10,
})
```

Which will be converted into:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT JOIN (ab JOIN b ON b.id = ab.bid) ON a.id = ab.aid
LIMIT 10

id  |  title    |   id  |  aid  |  bid  |  id   |  age
--- |  -------- | ----- | ----- | ----- | ----- | -----
1   |   first   |   1   |   1   |   1   |   1   |   1
1   |   first   |   2   |   1   |   2   |   2   |   2
1   |   first   |   3   |   1   |   3   |   3   |   3
1   |   first   |   4   |   1   |   4   |   4   |   4
1   |   first   |   5   |   1   |   5   |   5   |   5
2   |   second  |   6   |   2   |   5   |   5   |   5
2   |   second  |   7   |   2   |   4   |   4   |   4
2   |   second  |   8   |   2   |   3   |   3   |   3
2   |   second  |   9   |   2   |   2   |   2   |   2
2   |   second  |   10  |   2   |   1   |   1   |   1
```

After output is received, Seruqlize as ORM will make data mapping and over query result in code will be:

```
[
 {
  id: 1,
  title: 'first',
  ab: [
   { id: 1, age:1 },
   { id: 2, age:2 },
   { id: 3, age:3 },
   { id: 4, age:4 },
   { id: 5, age:5 },
  ],
 },
  {
  id: 2,
  title: 'second',
  ab: [
   { id: 5, age:5 },
   { id: 4, age:4 },
   { id: 3, age:3 },
   { id: 2, age:2 },
   { id: 1, age:1 },
  ],
 }
]
```

Obviously NOT what we wanted. I wanted to receive 10 records for A, but received just 2, while i know that there are more in database.

So we have correct SQL query but still received incorrect result.

Ok, i had some ideas but the easiest and most logical is:
1. Make first request with joins, and group results by source table (table on which we are making query and to which making joins) 'id'  property. Seems easy.....

````
To make so we need to provide 'group' property to Sequelize query options. Here we have some problems. First - Sequelize makes aliases for each table while generating SQL query. Second - Sequelize puts all columns from JOINED table into SELECT statement of its query and passing __'attributes' = []__ won't help. In both cases we'll receive SQL error.

To solve first we need to convert Model.tableName to singluar form of this word (this logic is based on Sequelize). Just use [pluralize.singular()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pluralize#usage). Then compose correct property to GROUP BY:
```ts
const tableAlias = pluralize.singular('Industries') // Industry

{
 ...,
 group: [`${tableAlias}.id`]
}
```

To solve second (it was the hardest and the most ... undocumented). We need to use undocumented property 'includeIgnoreAttributes' = false. This will remove all columns from SELECT statement unless we specify some manually. We should manually specify attributes = ['id'] on root query.
````

2. Now we will receive correctly output with only necessary resources ids. Then we need to compose seconf query WITHOUT limit and offset, but specify additional 'where' clause:

```
{
 ...,
 where: {
  ...,
  id: Sequelize.Op.in: [array of ids],
 }
}
```

3. With query about we can produce correct query with LEFT JOINS.

**Solution**
Method receives model and original query as arguments and returns correct query + additionally total amount of records in DB for pagination. It also correctly parse query order to provide ability to order by fields from joined tables:

```
/**
   *  Workaround for Sequelize illogical behavior when querying with LEFT JOINS and having LIMIT / OFFSET
   *
   *  Here we group by 'id' prop of main (source) model, abd using undocumented 'includeIgnoreAttributes'
   *  Sequelize prop (it is used in its static count() method) in order to get correct SQL request
   *  Witout usage of 'includeIgnoreAttributes' there are a lot of extra invalid columns in SELECT statement
   *
   *  Incorrect example without 'includeIgnoreAttributes'. Here we will get correct SQL query
   *  BUT useless according to business logic:
   *
   *  SELECT "Media"."id", "Solutions->MediaSolutions"."mediaId", "Industries->MediaIndustries"."mediaId",...,
   *  FROM "Medias" AS "Media"
   *  LEFT JOIN ...
   *  WHERE ...
   *  GROUP BY "Media"."id"
   *  ORDER BY ...
   *  LIMIT ...
   *  OFFSET ...
   *
   *  Correct example with 'includeIgnoreAttributes':
   *
   *  SELECT "Media"."id"
   *  FROM "Medias" AS "Media"
   *  LEFT JOIN ...
   *  WHERE ...
   *  GROUP BY "Media"."id"
   *  ORDER BY ...
   *  LIMIT ...
   *  OFFSET ...
   *
   *  @param model - Source model (necessary for getting its tableName for GROUP BY option)
   *  @param query - Parsed and ready to use query object
   */
  private async fixSequeliseQueryWithLeftJoins<C extends Model>(
    model: ModelCtor<C>, query: FindAndCountOptions,
  ): IMsgPromise<{ query: FindAndCountOptions; total?: number }> {
    const fixedQuery: FindAndCountOptions = { ...query };

    // If there is only Tenant data joined -> return original query
    if (query.include && query.include.length === 1 && (query.include[0] as IncludeOptions).model === Tenant) {
      return msg.ok({ query: fixedQuery });
    }

    // Here we need to put it to singular form,
    // because Sequelize gets singular form for models AS aliases in SQL query
    const modelAlias = singular(model.tableName);

    const firstQuery = {
      ...fixedQuery,
      group: [`${modelAlias}.id`],
      attributes: ['id'],
      raw: true,
      includeIgnoreAttributes: false,
      logging: true,
    };

    // Ordering by joined table column - when ordering by joined data need to add it into the group
    if (Array.isArray(firstQuery.order)) {
      firstQuery.order.forEach((item) => {
        if ((item as GenericObject).length === 2) {
          firstQuery.group.push(`${modelAlias}.${(item as GenericObject)[0]}`);
        } else if ((item as GenericObject).length === 3) {
          firstQuery.group.push(`${(item as GenericObject)[0]}.${(item as GenericObject)[1]}`);
        }
      });
    }

    return model.findAndCountAll<C>(firstQuery)
      .then((ids) => {
        if (ids && ids.rows && ids.rows.length) {
          fixedQuery.where = {
            ...fixedQuery.where,
            id: {
              [Op.in]: ids.rows.map((item: GenericObject) => item.id),
            },
          };
          delete fixedQuery.limit;
          delete fixedQuery.offset;
        }

        /* eslint-disable-next-line */
        const total = (ids.count as any).length || ids.count;

        return msg.ok({ query: fixedQuery, total });
      })
      .catch((err) => this.createCustomError(err));
  }
```