# Sequelize include same association twice with different criteria

Tags: node.js, postgresql, join, foreign-keys, sequelize.js

Say I have a table `suppliers`, which is associated to `tags` through another table `suppliers_tags`. So my model looks like this:

```
const Supplier = Sequelize.define('suppliers', {
  id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true },
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
});

const SupplierTag = Sequelize.define('suppliers_tags', {
  id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true },
  supplier_id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, references: { model: 'suppliers', key: 'id' } },
  tag_id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, references: { model: 'suppliers', key: 'id' } },
});

const Tag = Sequelize.define('tags', {
  id: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true },
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  type: Sequelize.ENUM('food', 'drink'),
});
```

The associations look like this:

```
Supplier.belongsToMany(Tag, { as: 'tags', through: 'suppliers_tags', foreignKey: 'supplier_id' });

Tag.belongsToMany(Supplier, { as: 'supplierTag', through: 'suppliers_tags', foreignKey: 'tag_id' });
```

Let's say I have the following data in the database:

suppliers:

```
id  name
1   Supplier1
2   Supplier2
3   Supplier3
```

tags:

```
id  name   type
1   Food1  food
2   Vegan  food
3   Vegan  drink
4   Food2  food
```

(I purposely named two tags the same, as for this application, it is important that tags with different types can have the same name.)

suppliers_tags

```
id  supplier_id  tag_id
1   1            1
2   1            3
3   1            2
4   2            1
5   2            4
6   3            2
```

Now I can do the following query:

```
Supplier.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Tag,
      as: 'tags',
      where: {
        [Op.and]: [
          { type: 'food' },
          { name: 'Vegan' },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

This returns Supplier1 and Supplier3, correctly joining on `suppliers_tags` and `tags` and filtering the `tags` table to include ones of `type` 'food' and `name` 'Vegan'.

Now, what if I want to search for suppliers where *both* the following conditions hold:

- The supplier has an associated tag which is of type `food` and name `Food1`
- The supplier has an associated tag which is of type `drink` and name `Vegan`

Naively (?), I tried the following:

```
Supplier.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: Tag,
      as: 'tags_food',
      where: {
        [Op.and]: [
          { type: 'food' },
          { name: 'Food1' },
        ],
      },
    },
    {
      model: Tag,
      as: 'tags_drink',
      where: {
        [Op.and]: [
          { type: 'drink' },
          { name: 'Vegan' },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

This tries to join the `tags` table twice, but neglecting to add aliases, resulting in the following error:

`SequelizeEagerLoadingError: tags is associated to suppliers multiple times. To identify the correct association, you must use the 'as' keyword to specify the alias of the association you want to include.`

Right, so it seems like the `as` options on the `include` didn't have the desired effect. What if I modify the associations to be the following:

```
Supplier.belongsToMany(Tag, { as: 'tags_drink', through: 'suppliers_tags', foreignKey: 'supplier_id' });
Supplier.belongsToMany(Tag, { as: 'tags_food', through: 'suppliers_tags', foreignKey: 'supplier_id' });

Tag.belongsToMany(Supplier, { as: 'supplierTag', through: 'suppliers_tags', foreignKey: 'tag_id' });
```

Now, if I run the same `findAll` query, it generates the following SQL:

```sql
SELECT
  "suppliers".*
  ,"tags_food"."id" AS "tags_food.id"
  ,"tags_food"."name" AS "tags_food.name"
  ,"tags_food"."type" AS "tags_food.type"
  ,"tags_food->suppliers_tags"."supplier_id" AS "tags_food.suppliers_tags.supplier_id"
  ,"tags_food->suppliers_tags"."tag_id" AS "tags_food.suppliers_tags.tag_id"
  ,"tags_drink"."id" AS "tags_drink.id"
  ,"tags_drink"."name" AS "tags_drink.name"
  ,"tags_drink"."type" AS "tags_drink.type"
  ,"tags_drink->suppliers_tags"."supplier_id" AS "tags_drink.suppliers_tags.supplier_id"
  ,"tags_drink->suppliers_tags"."tag_id" AS "tags_drink.suppliers_tags.tag_id"
FROM (
  SELECT
    "suppliers"."id"
    ,"suppliers"."name"
  FROM "suppliers" AS "suppliers"
  WHERE (
    SELECT "suppliers_tags"."supplier_id"
    FROM "suppliers_tags" AS "suppliers_tags"
    INNER JOIN "tags" AS "tag" ON "suppliers_tags"."tagId" = "tag"."id"
      AND ("tag"."type" = 'food' AND "tag"."name" = 'Food1')
    WHERE ("suppliers"."id" = "suppliers_tags"."supplier_id")
    LIMIT 1
  ) IS NOT NULL
  AND (
    SELECT "suppliers_tags"."supplier_id"
    FROM "suppliers_tags" AS "suppliers_tags"
    INNER JOIN "tags" AS "tag" ON "suppliers_tags"."tag_id" = "tag"."id"
      AND ("tag"."type" = 'drink' AND "tag"."name" = 'Vegan')
    WHERE ("suppliers"."id" = "suppliers_tags"."supplier_id")
    LIMIT 1
  ) IS NOT NULL
) AS "suppliers"
INNER JOIN (
  "suppliers_tags" AS "tags_food->suppliers_tags"
  INNER JOIN "tags" AS "tags_food"
    ON "tags_food"."id" = "tags_food->suppliers_tags"."tagId"
) ON "suppliers"."id" = "tags_food->suppliers_tags"."supplier_id"
  AND ("tags_food"."type" = 'food' AND "tags_food"."name" = 'Food1')
INNER JOIN (
  "suppliers_tags" AS "tags_drink->suppliers_tags"
  INNER JOIN "tags" AS "tags_drink"
    ON "tags_drink"."id" = "tags_drink->suppliers_tags"."tag_id"
) ON "suppliers"."id" = "tags_drink->suppliers_tags"."supplier_id"
  AND ("tags_drink"."type" = 'drink' AND "tags_drink"."name" = 'Vegan')
ORDER BY "suppliers"."id"
```

This is correct and what I need, except for one error: the foreign key `tag_id` has been switched to `tagId` (?!) in the case of the `tags_food` join. This then of course fails with the following error:

`SequelizeDatabaseError: column tags_food->suppliers_tags.tagId does not exist`

Notice that the *correct* foreign key `tag_id` was generated in the join on `tags_drink` by Sequelize.

If I switch around the relation definitions, i.e.:

```
Supplier.belongsToMany(Tag, { as: 'tags_food', through: 'suppliers_tags', foreignKey: 'supplier_id' });
Supplier.belongsToMany(Tag, { as: 'tags_drink', through: 'suppliers_tags', foreignKey: 'supplier_id' });

Tag.belongsToMany(Supplier, { as: 'supplierTag', through: 'suppliers_tags', foreignKey: 'tag_id' });
```

Then `tag_id` is produced successfully for the `tags_food` join and the weird `tagId` is produced for the `tags_drink` join.

Can I put this down to [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56171187/sequelize-condition-on-joined-table-doesnt-work-with-limit-condition?noredirect=1#comment99004656_56171187) basic flaw with Sequelize, or:

**Is there a defined way of joining the same relation twice on different criteria in Sequelize?**

Comment: Sequelize does not support a M:N relation between 3 columns, you'll have to do that manually on the db. I had the problem on the past and I had to do that and do the raw queries.